# Efficiently calculate result from an object fields and set the calculated result as value of a field in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have a MongoDB collection `Companies` like this:

```
[
  {
    "stock": "GOOGLE",
    "percentChange": 0
  },
  {
    "stock": "FACEBOOK",
    "percentChange": 0
  }
]
```

I have a large `StockPrices` object representing equity stocks and their prices:

```
'GOOGLE': {
  prices: {
    marketOpenPrice: 90.05,
    highestPriceInADay: 93.45,
    lowestPriceInADay: 90.05,
    marketClosePrice: 91.3
  }
},
'FACEBOOK': {
  prices: {
    marketOpenPrice: 10,
    highestPriceInADay: 15,
    lowestPriceInADay: 17,
    marketClosePrice: 12
  }
}
... and more companies like this
```

For each company in the MongoDB collection `Companies` , I need to calculate and set the `percentChange` with the following formula:

> profitLoss = marketOpenPrice - marketClosePrice;
>
> percentChange = (profitLoss / marketOpenPrice) * 100

I need to update each stock in the collection from the `StockPrices` object using Node.js.

I have thought of the following approach:

- Iterate over collection documents
- For each document, get the "stock" field value (GOOGLE, FACEBOOK)
- Calculate the `percentageChange` value from the `StockPrices.prices` wrt company using the above formula
- Update the document

This is an unacceptable approach because I have thousands and thousands of records and update is needed on an immediate basis.

In other words:

How do I efficiently calculate the result (in this case `percentageChange`) from an object (in this case `StockPrices`) fields (in this case `StockPrices.prices` fields) and set the calculated result as the value of a field (in this case `percentageChange`) in MongoDB collection (in this case `Companies`)

Comment: Side Note - instead of saving % change in `Companies` collection why not add % change in `StockPrices` while inserting them.

Comment: Because `Companies` collection is a **persistent data store** meaning it is available to other processes and `StockPrices` is only available only in **memory** when the function is running? Correct me if you thought otherwise :)